# What is more efficient, returning a pointer to a uint or a uint?

Tags: performance, pointers, go

In Go, what is more efficient to return from a function: returning a `uint` or returning a `*uint`?

The function is called in the inner for-loop of a cpu-intensive library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, whenever efficiency is the question, you should run benchmarks.

Let's create very simple examples:

```
func fuint() uint {
    return 0
}

func fpuint() *uint {
    var i uint
    return &i
}
```

And the benchmarking code:

```
func BenchmarkUint(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        fuint()
    }
}

func BenchmarkPuint(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        fpuint()
    }
}
```

One thing to look out for: since we have very simple functions, code optimization might render the result useless (e.g. we might see the same result).

So instead we should test by disabling compiler optimizations. So let's test it like this:

```
go test -gcflags '-N -l' -bench . -benchmem
```

The test results:

```
BenchmarkUint-4     500000000        3.21 ns/op      0 B/op     0 allocs/op
BenchmarkPuint-4    100000000       22.4 ns/op       8 B/op     1 allocs/op
```

Just as we could have guessed: allocating an `uint` value and returning a pointer to it is slower and requires an allocation (on the heap), while returning a simple `uint` value does not.

But don't think this is always the case. During this test, we disabled compiler optimizations. When you compile your app to production, you will obviously not disable optimizations, so your real-life examples might not have such big difference, or no difference at all. Test / benchmark your actual code to see if returning a pointer actually makes any noticeable difference.

For reference, here is the result with compiler optimizations enabled (default behavior):

```
go test -bench . -benchmem

BenchmarkUint-4     2000000000         0.35 ns/op        0 B/op      0 allocs/op
BenchmarkPuint-4    2000000000         0.35 ns/op        0 B/op      0 allocs/op
```

We see no difference for `fuint()` and `fpuint()` at all *in the specific examples above*.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. I was not aware of the compiler-flags either. But it seems that you have a space too many before `benchmem` in the test execution.

Comment: @nilsmagnus Yeah, that was a typo only in the answer, I did not have that when running the test.

Comment: Unfortunately, a microbenchmark with optimizations on doesn't really tell you much, because the optimizations are extremely context-sensitive - particularly things like elision and escape analysis. The only truly meaningful benchmark would be a benchmark of the code actually using this; microbenchmarks have very limited value and often do more harm than good by giving developers the impression that they've found a useful rule of thumb for performance.

Comment: @Adrian Exactly this is why the first benchmark is done with optimizations disabled, and the seconds is to show optimizations might have a great effect on this. And I also recommended in the answer that the asker should benchmark his actual, real code.